# Is there a way to find and replace all text in HTML for translation?

Tags: php, html, laravel, atom-editor

I previously made a website using Laravel. Now, I want to translate the website into other languages. Laravel provides good localization function, which involves replacing all text with function like this:

```
<!-- Original Text: -->
<div>Welcome!</div>
<!-- Replace with: -->
<div>{{Lang::get('messages.welcome')}}</div>
```

Laravel will then read the language files and replace with correct translation. It works great.

The only problem is that I need to find all the text in all my files and replace the text with that command by hand. Is there a tool to search all the text or would be even better automatically replace the text with the command?

P.S. I am using Atom, but other tools are also okay if it can do the find and replace job.

Comment: Have you already got the messages ready? Also, are they all so conveniently placed in `div` elements? If so, you probably need a sort of dictionary, so that you can look it up in reverse. Finally, if you’re prepared to run some code, such as in PHP, you can do a sort-of-parse to make the substitutions.

Comment: @Manngo No, they may not be placed in div. They may be in `<span>` and `<a>`. I have not got the message ready, because I need to have to sort out the message first before I do the translation.

Comment: No tools are going to accomplish this for you. This is going to require hand-by-hand re-doing of your Lang's. This is your life now.

Comment: How many documents are involved? Since container is not guaranteed, then you run the risk of false matches. Do you have access to PHP?

Comment: I am using laravel (a MVC framework in PHP), and the projects involves around 20 view files. Container is guarantee, but the container may contain other non-text elements too.